# Revolving the region $y=6-x^2$, $y=2x+3$ about x=5

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

To find the volume of the resulting solid we can either use rings or shells (parallel or perpendicular slices)
For this particular example using shells (parallel slices) makes it simple:
We have $\int (5-x)(6-x^2-2x-3) dx $ going from $x=-1$ to $x=3$ and the rest is simple. 
But when I attempt to setup the integrals of the inner and outer radii for the ring method :
1)the interval has to be divided to have one integral from $y=-3$ to $y=5$ and another one from $y=5$ to $y=6$ however I fail to setup the inner and outer radii and get the same result, I did a lot of tries involving random math to see if I would get the same result but no avail...
TL;DR
Can you find the volume using rings, explaining anything that has to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs of all, the bounds of integration for the shell method should be from $−3$ to $1$ because those are the roots of the equation $6-x^2=2x+3$:

$$
V=2\pi\int_{-3}^{1}\left[(5-x)(6-x^2-(2x+3))\right]\,dx=128\pi\ cubic\ units.
$$

[Wolfram Alpha check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%202*pi*(5-x)*(6-x%5E2-(2x%2B3))%20dx%20from%20-3%20to%201).

And this is your integral for the washer method (I assume that's what you mean by "rings"):

$$
V=
\pi\int_{-3}^{5}\left[\left(5-\left(-\sqrt{6-y}\right)\right)^2-\left(5-\frac{y-3}{2}\right)^2\right]\,dy+\\
\pi\int_{5}^{6}\left[\left(5-\left(-\sqrt{6-y}\right)\right)^2-\left(5-\sqrt{6-y}\right)^2\right]\,dy=\\
\frac{344\pi}{3}+\frac{40\pi}{3}=
128\pi\ cubic\ units.
$$

As you can see, the integration should be done with respect to $y$. [The first integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi*((5-(-sqrt(6-x)))%5E2-(5-(x-3)%2F2)%5E2)dx+from+-3+to+5) on Wolfram Alpha and [the second one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi*((5-(-sqrt(6-x)))%5E2-(5-sqrt(6-x))%5E2)dx+from+5+to+6). That's just a check. If there is something you don't understand, don't hesitate to ask. But the main idea with the waster method is that you subtract the smaller volume from the bigger one.

[image]

And you do a similar thing for the other piece.

Comment: Well Thank you, something wrong is going on, I am stuck on this example for three days now, Yes the interval is from - 3 to 1 I just had a typo there, I can figure out that I do have a problem with rotation about lines, I did the same two integrals as yours using the washer method but with $(5-sqrt(6-y))$ as the outer radius as well as the inner radius, and I think I did the same in all. The examples before this and did get the correct answer, what I mean here is when measuring the outer radius from $x=5$ we get $5+f(y)$ as $f(y) =-sqrt(6-y)$ is in negative x-axis.

Comment: Well, $y=-\sqrt{6-y}$ lies below the y-axis (turn your coordinate system $90^\circ$ to the right and flip it over). In roder to get the whole radius, you need to add $5$ to the distance between the y-axis and $y=-\sqrt{6-y}$ and for that you need to negate the function. The same logic applies the other piece. And then you subtract the volumes.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by negate, you mean taking the magnitude (modulus) of the function?

Comment: By that, I merely mean put a minus sing in front of the function because otherwise you would be subtracting $-\sqrt{6-y}$ from $5$ and that's not the distance from the line $x=5$ and the curve $y=-\sqrt{6-y}$

Comment: I know that this is getting silly, but why didn't we do the same to the part of the straight line which is in the negative y-axis, after all do you know any good source that explains the topic?

Comment: To be honest I don't know of any good source that perfectly explains this topic. All I can do is draw you a picture of what exactly is going on. Maybe, that will help.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have said $x=-\sqrt{6-y}$ up there, not $y=-\sqrt{6-y}$.

Comment: Well I looked at your graph, and everything made sense to me when I plugged numbers to the functions and asked my self if I would add or subtract, though We could have done this with out rotation, after all $THANK YOU$ for your effort #Total_Respect.

Comment: Well, it certainly is easier to calculate that volume using the shell method, but if the requirement is to find the volume using the washer method, then it could also be done. It's just going to be a whole lot more difficult. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You are right we have to use parallel slices but the integrand should be $2\pi(5 - x)dxdy$.  You are also correct to split the volume into two integrals with different limits.  The integral should be

$$\int_{5}^{6}\int_{- \sqrt{6 - y}}^{\sqrt{6 - y}}2\pi (5 - x)dxdy + \int_{-3}^{5} \int_{-\sqrt{6 - y}}^{\frac{y - 3}{2}} 2\pi (5 - x)dxdy = 128\pi$$